# Android whastapp call to reject or not

Tags: java, android, call, block, whatsapp

Android/Java: I'm trying to block WhatsApp calls but I'm not being able to do it. Does anyone have a way to intercept the WhatsApp call? I would only need to obtain the number and the call button, to be able to verify it and then decide whether to reject it or not.

I already tried using BroadcastReceiver and PhonestateListener but those only work with regular calls. I also tried to search for apps in the playstore but none of them have blocking exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting and blocking WhatsApp calls is not supported by Whatsapp. WhatsApp has implemented measures to prevent unauthorized access to its call functionalities for third-party apps. Also it violate user privacy and security policy at least in my country. So You might get into legality issue when app goes live, So please refer whatsapp policies for your country before working on it.

Comment: There are many applications in the PlayStore that block WhatsApp calls but none of them have an exception option: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callcenter.whatsblock.call.blocker